# DOMPDF: The right content jumps to next page when left column content exceeds

Tags: php, css, pdf-generation, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I'm using DOMPDF for html to pdf conversion in PHP. I've simple CSS for creating two columns in DOMPDF. But whenever content in left column increases, the content of right column jumps to next page. I've tried with page-break CSS but didn't get result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTo1q.png

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.one {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.two {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="one">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quod consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti? Laboriosam perspiciatis labore maxime ex, dolorum nisi nam, mollitia itaque, dolor quod vitae quisquam! Aperiam, quia ipsa?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quod consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti? Laboriosam perspiciatis labore maxime ex, dolorum nisi nam, mollitia itaque, dolor quod vitae quisquam! Aperiam, quia ipsa?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quod consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti? Laboriosam perspiciatis labore maxime ex, dolorum nisi nam, mollitia itaque, dolor quod vitae quisquam! Aperiam, quia ipsa?</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quod consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti? Laboriosam perspiciatis labore maxime ex, dolorum nisi nam, mollitia itaque, dolor quod vitae quisquam! Aperiam, quia ipsa?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quod consequuntur voluptatibus corrupti? Laboriosam perspiciatis labore maxime ex, dolorum nisi nam, mollitia itaque, dolor quod vitae quisquam! Aperiam, quia ipsa?</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: maybe it's because of default margins of divs. try to reset devis via `*{margin:0}` or set a width lesser than 50% for your columns

Comment: Actually, I've already set margin, padding to zero for *, html and body. Also, I've tried by reducing width to each column but none of it works

Comment: I'm in exactly the same scenario and have the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Well ... I used mpdf instead of dompdf and I had no problem with same css. Besides, mpdf provides more features than dompdf.